# Blocking Port 80 and other ports on a cPanel account when malicious files are found

Tags: hosting, cpanel, whm

Many shared hosting have the feature of blocking Port no 80 and other ports on a cPanel account when malicious files are detected on that cPanel account.

Can you let me know how can i implement this feature in WHM Panel. Which plugin/software do i need to install on WHM panel for this feature to work

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for something similar

**Screenshot links:**

- https://ibb.co/c7yVQV
- https://ibb.co/eGqzKq